# How to Assign a Custom Operator to an Intrinsic Function in Fortran

Tags: interface, fortran, operator-overloading

I'm using Intel Visual Fortran 2015 with Visual Studio 2012. I'm wanting to create an operator overload for an intrinsic function in the simplest way.

This is what I tried but it gives an error, and while I understand the error says I can't do this I can't think of an elegant way to do this without having to create multiple overloaded functions to call the intrinsic and do it that way.

Is there an easier way than that?

```
Program main
  implicit none

  interface operator (.matmul.)
    procedure matmul
  end interface

  real*8, dimension(3,3) :: a, b, c

  c = a .matmul. b

  write(*,*) c

end program main
```

The error message is:

> error #8574: A procedure-name in a generic interface block must be a nonintrinsic procedure that has an explicit interface. [MATMUL]

Comment: I'd say, yes, your own "wrappers" would be necessary.  But it may not be as awful as you may think.  [It won't be fun enough to make it worth the effort, surely.]  Is your `matmul` example just an example (so we can't just focus on "just stick to using the function, or very specific hacks), or do you want this more generally?

Comment: Yes I'd agree with francescalus and say that having a wrapper may not be that bad idea after all. For instance in case if you want to have different implementations of the same functionality (i.e. using matmul and for instance BLAS function). In this case a wrapper will be an easy to implement and in the same time quite flexible solution.

Comment: As far as what I'm currently working on it is really only matmul() that I am working with, but I was curious about the in general "correct" solution to the issue. Honestly, the only reason I want to do it  this way is because I think breaking things like A*(B*C) into two lines is silly, and doing matmul(A, matmul(B,C)) is ugly, so I was just wanting to make it look like A .matmul. (B .matmul. C). Purely cosmetic usage.

Comment: I also wasn't sure if there is any sort of performance hit in doing a wrapper function which is also something I'd like to avoid, as there are quite a few matrix multiplications at a very high data rate.